# Open multiple instances of an app (spark e-mail app)

Tags: terminal

I would like to use an app multiple times. I installed Spark which is from my point of view a great email app. I have two companies with various accounts (pr@...,contact@...) and instead of having all of them in the same app I'd like to have spark1.app for company1 and the same for company2/spark2.app for example.

I already tried `open -n -a APPNAME` but Spark is telling me that there already is a copy running !

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you tried saving the copy to a different location (like the desktop)? If this doesn't work, it's possible the app won't let you run multiple instances. (I have run multiple instances of PS, Handbrake, and similar by launching them from other computers on the same network).

Comment: I just did... and unfortunately that didn't work out. Same warning message !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you get two copies running, they're both going to be sharing the same set of prefs & repositories... & both trying to write to them at the same time.

This is a very bad idea.

If you want two mail apps handling two different mail accounts simultaneously, use two **different** mail apps.

Comment: It's just quite sad that there's no option to dissociate there prefs and repos...

Comment: There is, but it has to be done by the developer before compile. You can't do it after the fact.